# How to use SQLCipher on PHP for SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite, sqlcipher

how can I use SQLCipher on PHP on regular PHP, Apache installation or any other WAMP, ZendServer and so on... On Windows not linux?

OR

How can I use this method for encryption in PHP: http://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

I need AES encryption for SQLite3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find instructions on building SQLCipher for PHP [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-php)

Comment: This is for ubanutu operating system what if we have windows operating system

Answer (score -1):

Try this, once installed and enabled in php mods on Wamp (should already be installed):

```
<?php
try {
  $db = new SQLite3("demo.db");
  $version = $db->query("PRAGMA cipher_version");
  if($version){
    var_dump($version->fetchArray());
  } else {
    throw new Exception($db->lastErrorMsg());
  }
  $db->close();
}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo "Exception", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: this is for sqlite not sqlcipher